# How to parse JSON strings with single quotes (') in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, json, parsing

I am trying to parse a JSON String like this:

```
JSON.parse("{'foo' : 42 }")
```

However, this yields a JSON::ParseError:

```
JSON::ParserError: 757: unexpected token at '{'foo' : 42 }'
    from /Users/nils/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/json/common.rb:155:in `parse'
    from /Users/nils/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/json/common.rb:155:in `parse'
    from (irb):2
    from /Users/nils/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
```

I think it expects the `'` character to be a `"` character. Since I have multiple gigabytes of such files I would like to make the parser work with this. Since some of the values may also include `'` characters I can't simply run search and replace over them because that may destroy the original content.

Any suggestions on how to make the JSON parser parse this?

Comment: A problem is best solved where it occurs. If you try to solve it later, you get in more trouble. In this case, what is wrong is that you got that invalid JSON string. You should try to fix whatever that gave you the wrong string, rather than trying to force the parser to read an invalid JSON.

Comment: I don't think it is a valid json. check here too http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: By the way, a tick is ` . A `'` is called a single quote.

Comment: The problem is that I get the files the way they are, I cannot regenerate them myself correctly. :/

Comment: You could write a simple converter using JavaScript.  Just load the files using `eval` (because they ARE valid JavaScript, if not valid JSON) and re-serialize them using `JSON.stringify`.

Comment: For __hacks__ sake, you could try to replace (all) single with double quotes: JSON.parse "{'foo' : 42 }".gsub(/'/, "\"")

Comment: Ah, well. The JSON is an export from MySQL workbench. A newer version fixed the the single quotes issue but still it is not able to generate valid JSON. Guess I will have to get access to the original database then since just replacing all single quotes is not an option.

Answer (score 6):

> I am trying to parse a JSON String like this:
>
> ```
> JSON.parse("{'foo' : 42 }")
> ```

That's not a JSON string.

> However, this yields a `JSON::ParseError`:

Which is correct, since the string is not JSON.

> Any suggestions on how to make the JSON parser parse this?

You cannot parse this with a JSON parser because it's not JSON.

You need to figure out what language it is, and then use a parser for that language.

The snippet you posted looks like [YAML](http://YAML.Org/), but of course that could just be accidental.

```
require 'yaml'

YAML.load("{'foo' : 42 }")
# => { "foo" => 42 }
```

But note that trying to guess the language from one single, short example is highly error-prone. You should confer with the producer of that serialization and ask them what language it is.