# Ruby Read file without escaping the characters

Tags: json, ruby, string, parsing, hash

File Content:

```
file.txt:
{ 'a' : 'b"c\g' }
```

Need to parse this JSON.

```
read_file = File.read(file.txt)
```

This read_file string is of the form : `"{ 'a' : 'b\"c\\g'}\n"`.

While parsing the JSON:

```
JSON::ParserError: 757: unexpected token at '{ 'a' : 'b"c\g'}
    from /usr/share/ruby/json/common.rb:155:in `parse'
    from /usr/share/ruby/json/common.rb:155:in `parse'
    from (irb):21
    from /usr/bin/irb:12:in `<main>`
```

The file could contain any escaping sequence or wild-cards, but it will always be in JSON format.

How to parse such JSON file to ruby Hash?

Comment: It doesn't look like JSON.

Comment: That JSON is clearly invalid. `JSON` strings must be wrapped in double quotes e.g. `{"a":"b\"c\\g"}` *"A string is a sequence of Unicode code points wrapped with quotation marks (U+0022)"* - **ECMA 404**.

Comment: When showing sample code, try and show it as actual code, not some rough approximation.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the json in your text file is invalid. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25243979/how-to-parse-json-strings-with-single-quotes-in-ruby) is a similar question about parsing a json string using single quotes. For this to be valid json it needs

1. Double quotes
2. Escaped special characters

Without this you'll be unable to parse it as it won't be recognized as valid json. Try parsing this text instead:

`{ "a": "b\"c\\g" }` => `{"a"=>"b\"c\g"}`